# Backbone js after click event and navigate to new adress view is not changed

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, navigateurl

Hello stackoverflowers !!!

I have problem with render view after click event :

```
var TablesView = Backbone.View.extend({       

    events: {
      "click li" : "openMenuItem"
    },

    openMenuItem: function(e){
      currentLink = $(e.currentTarget);
      tableId = currentLink.data('table_id');
      app.navigate("table/" + tableId + "/menus");
      console.log("table/" + tableId + "/menus");
    },  

        initialize:function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
        var that = this;
        var tables = new Tables();
        tables.fetch({
            success: function (tables) {
            var template = _.template($('#table-template').html(), {tables: tables.models});
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }             
});
```

So when I click to one of my `li` I have in adress bar rigth adress but View is not changed, only when I click to adress bar and press enter ... (My url /table/:id/menus is function properly but is not opened with click event only when I have in template `a` link )

Thanks for answers...
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass `trigger` option:

```
app.navigate("table/" + tableId + "/menus", true); // or
app.navigate("table/" + tableId + "/menus", {trigger:true});
```

Of course if your `app` is an instance of `Backbone.Router` :)

Comment: But when I go back function is not working... You don't know why ? Thanks

Comment: It would be good to have a jsfiddle with issue reproduction. Because I do not know what and why is not working.